# How could I set the default Azure Workbook group state to expanded?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-analysis-services, appinsights, expanded

How could I set the default Azure Workbook group state to expanded?

I want to `Show expand / collapse in title of group`, but also I want the state to be expanded when a user sees the group for the first time. Right now (by default I assume) the default state is collapse. Is there a way to set the initial value for the collapsed/expanded?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Yes, it is possible to set the initial value for the collapsed/expanded.***

I found a workaround by editing the `JSON` configuration of a group.

*I created one random workbook group and entered the data shown below and then clicked on edit.*

[image]

*In the existing JSON schema, I added the following configuration values to show expand/set the initial state:*

```json
"showExpandCollapse":  true
"initialState":  "expanded"
```

*After you've finished editing the `json` configuration, click "Done editing" to save the changes.*

[image]